# What is a formula that checks if a number is negative?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, integers, number-systems

I am working on a project involving different number systems. Right now I am trying to come up with a non-recursive formula about converting a decimal number into the binary equivalent. Right now I have the following problem:

How can I construct a formula that gives 1 if the input number is non-negative (including 0), and 0 if it is negative?

I have come up with a way to do this but it fails when the number I'm checking is exactly 0...

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: If you are given a *decimal* number, I assume you are given a character string consisting of digits, perhaps a single decimal point, and perhaps a single sign character in the beginning. Such s string represents a negative number iff the first character is '`-`'

Comment: If you are rather given a real number, you can try $f(x):=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }x\ge 0\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$.

Comment: If neither of the two above comments solves your problem, you may want to specify more clearly, what you consider to be a valid 'formula'.

Comment: Yeah, basically I am looking for the mathematical notation of a formula equivalent to the function you provided. My original idea, for example, was to add the number to its absolute value (and multiply the whole thing by 1/(2*input number)). This works in every case but 0...

Comment: What I wrote *is* a mathematical notation. If you restrict yourself to finitely nested elementary functions, then the result will always be a function that is *continuous* on its domain (because that is true for all elementary functions).

Comment: @AtanasIliev So you are willing to use the absolute value? Do you realize that the DEFINITION of absolute value is $|x| = \begin{cases}x&\text{if }x\ge 0\\-x&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$
If you accept that, you should accept the answer of Hagen von Eitzen

Comment: The more efficient would be a test e.g. `(x<0)?0:1` in C for instance, but you can always replace a test by a piecewise function of your choice. See this link for characteristic function of intervals https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3218157/399263

Comment: Unclear if this helps.  The following formula can **only** be used for $x \neq 0.$ Use this: $$\frac{1}{2} \times \left(\frac{x}{|x|} ~+~ 1\right).$$  Note that this formula **assumes** absolutely no rounding error, which might well be an unwarranted assumption.