# Is it possible to write this piecewise-defined function as a regular function?

Tags: functions, piecewise-continuity

I have this piecewise-defined function:
$$
g(a, b, e) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
1 - e & \text{if }a > b,\\
0.5 & \text{if }a = b,\\
e & \text{if }a < b
\end{array}\right.
$$
$$
e \in \mathopen(0,0.5\mathclose)
$$
I need it so that it can be written without the if else.
I already figured that it would be possible to have -1 or 1 depending on whether a is greater than b or vice versa:
$$
\text{sign} = \frac{a-b}{|a-b|}
$$
However, I am stuck here. Is this possible at all?

Comment: What's a regular function to you? Algebraic? Analytic? Are series representations fine to you, even if they're not power series?

Comment: You write $g(x)$ but also $a$ and $b$, but what are $a$ and $b$? Did you mean $g(a)$?

Comment: I have corrected my notation. The point for me is that I need to code this function (e.g., in python) without using any form of ifelse.

Comment: You may be interested by the generalization I made here for any indicator function. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3218157/399263

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the sign function you defined, you could take

$$g(x)=e+\frac{1-2e}{2}\left(1+\frac{a-b}{|a-b|}\right)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{a-b}{|a-b|}\left(\frac{1}{2}-e\right)$$

This if $a>b$, we get $e+(1-2e)=1-e$ and if $a<b$ we get $e+0=e$. We still have zero-division problems when $a=b$, but I believe this will always be the case when trying to write functions that are discontinuous in their parameters as `regular' functions.

**EDIT**:
If you want to code this in Python, you can actually use the cases natively in your formula. If they are true, they will evaluate to $1$, else $0$. Hence, your function could look like

`e*(a>b) + 0.5*(a==b) + (1-e)*(a<b)`

Comment: Thank you very much! This is very close to what I am looking for. It would be great if the case of $a = b$ could be included, too. But maybe this will already work. Thank you!

Comment: Updated to reflect your Python comment. Since this is a more of a coding problem, it's probably easier to look for a coding shortcut rather than a fancy mathematical solution (unless that's what you're after)

Comment: I think I won't be able to use (a==b) but I will give it a try. I think the mathematical solution will be easier than solving this in coding (I am using an external package and it seems to be quite complicated -> point is I can't use comparisons of any form in my function).

Comment: Using try/except, it seems to work and catches the condition of a=b